# Matlab:Image processing, collect 3 color channel's pixel

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i'm trying to addition rgb channel pixel value.It will be easy,but i'm a fresh hand in matlab.
For red channel it's my code;

```
for i=1:width
for t=1:height
    value=y(i,t,1);
    red=red+value;    
  end
```

end

red is 255 but it must be different from 255.How i can addition?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
red=sum(sum(y(:,:,1)));
```